# shorten querystring for searching and many filters

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, serialization, query-string

i am building a search function which use many filters. i decide to use the get method instead of post (different reasons). Problem is, when using many filters the querystring gets very long, especially when i use filter with same name so i get

```
myurl.com?filter1[]=val1&filter1[]=val2&filter2=val
```

To get better control and to prevent 0 values i tried serializeArray:

```
var array = {}; 
jQuery.each(jQuery('form').serializeArray(), function(index,val) {
if (val.value != 0 )
    array[value.name] = val.value;
});
```

But this way it overrides the first filter1 with the last value of filter1, so multiple values doesn´t work. And then i have the "problem" to create the querystring. I am not a javascript prof. so i need a little help here.

What can i do, so i get a querystring which looks like:

```
myurl.com?filter1=val1|val2&filter2=val and so on
```

The HTML are "normal" input fields

```
<input type="checkbox" name="filter1[]" />
<input type="text" name="filter2" />
```

Thank you in advance

ruven

Comment: You'll have to show us what your raw data that you are starting with looks like before we can advise how to convert it into a shorter URL.  I assume here that the RAW data is the state of your HTML so I think we need to see what your HTML is like.

Comment: hi jfriend00 i edited it. The data come from input fields in html

Comment: I think you have everything okay here, you should get a nice array in PHP, like $_POST['filter1'] would be array('val1', 'val2'), why is that bad?

Comment: @RuvenJR.Maerson - it isn't clear to me how from the HTML you provided how you get multiple values for the same filter name and that is the part of the question you are asking us to help with.  We don't know what your page looks like and you're asking us to solve a problem that requires that information.  All we could do now is guess.  Specific and accurate answers require seeing your actual HTML for the problem you're asking about.

Comment: `jQuery.each(jQuery('form').serializeArray(), function(index,val) {...});`???  `.serializeArray()` returns a string and `$.each` on a string is nonsense. Your only realistic hope is to POST instead of GET.

Comment: `serializeArray` [certainly does not return a string](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/).

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot GET is not an option and not a good way of coding, since user hits back key (they often do) you get a mess e.g. in ff (document expired).

Comment: OK, but do you mean POST? That's what I'm suggesting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this ([working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/VFCw8/3/)):

```
<form action="search.html">
    <input type="text" value="val1" name="filter1" />
    <input type="text" value="val2" name="filter1" />
    <input type="text" value="val" name="filter2" />
    <input type="submit" value="search" name="cmdSearch" />
</form>
​
<script>
    // don't do anything until document is ready
    $(function() {

        // register to form submit event
        $('form').submit(function(e){

            // stop the form from doing its default action (submit-GET)
            e.preventDefault();

            // initialise url
            var url = '';

            // keep track of previously enumerated field
            var prev = '';      

            // iterate all fields in the form except the submit button(s)
            $('input:not([type="submit"])', $(this)).each(function(){

                // get the name of this field, with null coalesce
                var name = $(this).attr('name') || '';

                // get the value of this field
                var val = $(this).attr('value');

                // does this field have the same name as the previous?
                if (name.toLowerCase() == prev.toLowerCase()) {

                    // same name therefore we have already appended the name
                    // append value separator
                    url += '|';
                }
                else {

                    // different name, track new name
                    prev = name;

                    // append parameter separator, parameter name, equals char
                    url += '&' + name + '=';
                }

                // append value of this field         
                url += val;
            });

            // removing leading ampersand
            if (url.length && [0] == '&') {
                url = url.substring(1);            
            }       

            // insert leading question mark
            url = '?' + url;

            // insert url from "action" attribute of the form
            url = $(this).attr('action') + url;

            // display url (delete this line)
            alert(url);

            // redirect to the new url (simulates the GET)
            window.location.href = url;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: man you are the best. i really dont understand your code, but this is what i am looking for. Maybe you can explain it a bit? Would be nice, so i understand it a little better.

Comment: ah now i understand it better. Think i have a learn much in javascript. Thank you well for your service.